# PAAS (e.g. Heroku, .. AWS?) vs my concept of a web host provider (e.g. FTP uploading)

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to understand what the key differences are between providers such as Heroku (PAAS?) and my host providers I've always used for my PHP apps (currently hosting24.com):

My PHP apps I basically just write the app locally then upload the specified files using my FTP client. The app then runs when a page is requested. I can still use Git version control but it's only local and nothing to do with deployment.

My Rails apps I write the app locally, as I do PHP. Commit changes, as I do with PHP. However, I can also use Git to push the entire site/version up to Heroku. Heroku appears to do lots of things (e.g. compress assets) and then, once finished, my site is ready.

What is my web hot provider (for my PHP apps) that Heroku is not, and vice versa? Are they just essentially the same thing but Heroku is Git enabled (instead of providing FTP access), and allows commands to be run through terminal etc and can handle a remote push to the server. I've been coding for about 10 years, only recently taken up RoR, so my concept of a web host provider is being seriously challenged :) I've always just put the files online via FTP and as far as I know that's all that is being done. Is this a Rails thing where Gems have to be loaded, app recompiled etc. Can anyone clarify a little, or direct me somewhere that can.

Also, is Amazon AWS just the same idea as Heroku but with different features, different price plan, specs etc. Are they comparable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forced version control with git is one difference between heroku and other general hosting sites but I think the main advantage of heroku is the availability of myriads of plugins and add-ons on one-click, and the ability to scale up to 100 nodes instantly. If you suddenly meet a huge traffic, you can just scale your application accordingly. You can also decrease the number of nodes when there a re less traffic. There are also various node types of performance.

Probably the down side of it is that you are forced to use third party cloud storage system such as Amazon S3 because you cannot store dynamic files like user uploaded files on the nodes, though I think it is a better practice in general.